# how to dismiss a view that has been replaced by another one properly

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two views that are associated with the same `div` element:

```
MuSe.views.View1= Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#applicationCanvas",
    ...

MuSe.views.View2= Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#applicationCanvas",
    ...
```

I begin with rendering `View1` and when the user terminates the interaction I want to replace everything with `View2`.

I would like to dismiss `View1` properly (unbind it from the `div` `#applicationCanvas` so that the garbage collector can do its job) and to do so I call `undelegateEvents()` on it. I can't call `remove()` because I need `#applicationCanvas` for `View2`. I was wondering if calling `undelegateEvents` and replacing the entire dom subtree of `#applicationCanvas` was enough. What's your say?

Thanks

### Update

along with `undelegateEvents()` I call `stopListening()` as well

Comment: Why not stop doing `el: "#applicationCanvas"` and put the views *inside* `#applicationCanvas`? Yes yes, extra `<div>`s and all that but it will reduce your problem to a simple `view.remove()` call.

Comment: I simply was wondering if this practice is possible. This would keep my app quite neat :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so.. according to [the official backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) what I do is perfectly allowed! Of course this could change with a new version of Backbone, so heads up!

Backbone's remove:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

what I did without calling remove:

```
view1.stopListening();
view1.undelegateEvents();
view2.render();           //<-- it will replace all the content
```

Comment: Um, what do you think `this.$el.remove()` does to your `#applicationCanvas`?

Comment: I thought about that, but since I replace everything inside the div, the result should be the same

Comment: sorry, I've never used coffeescript, but I'm wondering why this is not working properly [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6XZD5/2/) . It should display V1 right?

Comment: ok, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/6XZD5/3/
I really don't get what's wrong. It does what we expect, right?

Comment: The problem is that `view.remove()` remove's `view.el` from the DOM so if you use `remove`, your second view will no longer have an `el`. If you let Backbone create the `el` itself then removing it will be fine. Overriding `remove` as in your answer with `this.$el.remove()` replaced with something like `this.$el.html('')` would be better, then you could just `view.remove()` as usual and not worry about it.

Comment: oh, now I get it! Of course you are absolutely right! What I post in my answer is the backbone's remove, not my override. I'll modify my answer in order to be clear